# SimpleDateFormat - Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I try to convert String to Date.

Here is my code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date date = format.parse("Sun Apr 08 16:37:00 CEST 2012");
```

I get exception:

> 04-08 13:51:36.536: W/System.err(8005): java.text.ParseException:
>   Unparseable date: "Sun Apr 08 16:37:00 CEST 2012".

Format seems to be ok. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but still throws the same exception.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Try recompiling your code after making changes. (Unless you have some weird locale issue going on)

Comment: Why was this question voted down? Users should post an explanation of how the question could be improved instead of just clicking the down arrow.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781257/unexpected-java-simpledateformat-parse-exception

Comment: The question seems legit to me. Can you supply additional information on which Android platform this happened? Did you that happen on a "real" android device or in the emulator.

Comment: @BrianRoach So why not flag the question as a duplicate in the first place instead of rushing in to post a comment (which in this case is incorrect, a second `d` is not required here).

Comment: As @BrianRoach already stated below, it might be a Locale problem. What Locale does your device run on?

Answer (score 8):

Either the code you posted is not your actual code, or you have a locale issue. It works fine on <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle Java 1.6 with a US locale.

Change your code to:

```
SimpleDateFormat format =  
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: Heh - see my edit note. I actually had to go back and change it ... I'll never get used to "Oracle Java"

Comment: Thank you my friend. Your code solved an issue that I spent hours trying to figure it out

Answer (score 5):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) specific. At least the pattern `E` and `M` are locale specific, because for example "Sun" or "Sunday" will not match for Locale.GERMAN or Locale.FRENCH etc. You better specify the used Locale

```
SimpleDateFormat format =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
```

or use a format, which is not locale specific.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers were fine answers in 2012. Here’s an example of how to do with the modern (2014) Java date and time classes:

```
    System.out.println("date de la requete est " + dateq);
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss xx uuuu", Locale.ROOT);
    OffsetDateTime dateTime1 = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateq, dtf);

    System.out.println("new date " + dateTime1);
```

The code example was inspired from a duplicate question (as I see it), [How to convert Xml String date to int in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351846/how-to-convert-xml-string-date-to-int-in-java). With the example string from that question it prints:

```
date de la requete est Tue Feb 08 12:30:27 +0000 2011
new date 2011-02-08T12:30:27Z
```

Q: I cannot use the newer classes on Android(?)

A: Yes you can. For Android, use the backport specifically tailored to Android, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). Otherwise for Java 6 and 7, use [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Q: Your code doesn’t work for the date-time string in *this* question!

A: (1) If you can, avoid the three and four letter time zone abbreviations like CEST. Many are ambiguous and interpretation may even vary with your JVM’s current time zone setting. CEST is just the summer half of a time zone, not a full time zone. (2) If you cannot get a string without `CEST` or similar in it, try using `ZonedDateTime` instead of `OffsetDateTime` and use `zzz` in the format pattern as in the question. This works in the example and produces `2012-04-08T16:37+02:00[Europe/Paris]`.

Q: How do I use the newer classes?

A: One good place to start is the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Q: `Locale.ROOT`??

A: If your date-time string comes from a specific place in the world and in the language of that place, use the corresponding locale, of course. If it’s just in English because computer systems everywhere tend to output English, I prefer to use `Locale.ROOT` for “the locale neutral locale”, like saying “do not do anything locale-specific here”.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like "Sun" isn't recognized.
Try this:

```
date = format.parse("Sunday Apr 08 16:37:00 CEST 2012");
```

Works for me.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html it doesn't matter if it is the abbrev (Sun) or the full word (Sunday).