# Java Date parsing from specific String format under Android env

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

What's wrong with below date format? I'm getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date Thu, 03 May 2012 14:00:00 CEST

```
String inputDate = "Thu, 03 May 2012 14:00:00 CEST";
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
Date parsedDate = DATE_FORMATTER.parse(inputDate);
```

I have tried below combinations but am out of luck:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US);
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US);
```

I'm getting the same exception if modify CEST to CET, but not for PST. Any pointer will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you tried with zzzz ? (shouldn't work, but still)

Comment: If I ignore timezone by removing 'z', then I won't get the exception.

Comment: it seems you're not the only one to have the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062608/simpledateformat-unparseable-date

Comment: can you change the CEST to +0200 ? (change the timezone formating from name to value?)

Comment: The same code works in Windows but not in Android emulators :(. By the way, I'm getting Thu May 03 12:00:00 GMT 2012 in Android by replacing CEST with +0200. Any idea why CEST doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Its working... see this..

**-** Please correct the typo from `inputDateString` to `inputDate` in `parse()`

Its a **Working Java Code...**  Modify it to suit your Android use....

```
public class CopyArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputDate = "Thu, 03 May 2012 14:00:00 CEST";
        SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        try {
            Date parsedDate = DATE_FORMATTER.parse(inputDate);
            System.out.println(parsedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @njzk2 i gave a working Java code here, so he can modify and try it to his heart content before putting this into Android....

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the minor issue that you are trying to parse `inputDateString` when your variable is actually called `inputDate`, I'm able to run your code with no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me too

```
package test.java;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String inputDate = "Thu, 03 May 2012 14:00:00 CEST";
        SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        Date parsedDate = DATE_FORMATTER.parse(inputDate);
        System.out.println("Date = " + parsedDate);
    }
}
```

And the output I get is:

Date = Thu May 03 13:00:00 BST 2012

Comment: still not an android related answer

Comment: Hmm... I just test it out on my Windows host and it works! I guess it should be either environment issue or a bug in Android.

Comment: @njzk2 - It didn't specifically mention Android in the question. (I know it said Android in the tag, but it said Java as well ;-))

Comment: @shiouming - Apologies, I don't know anything about Android development....sorry!

Comment: no worry, dave. thanks for your response. initially i thought it's generic java question. i shall tweak the question.

Comment: from other related questions, it seems there is something specific to android on this issue