# ParseException when parsing valid date

Tags: java, android, parsing, http-headers, simpledateformat

I'm receiving reports of two Android clients having problems when parsing the date of a HTTP response. I'm logging the date the client is trying to parse, and it is perfectly OK.

The block that parses the date is:

```
    public Date parseDateInHeader(String dateHeader) throws ParseException {
       SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss 'GMT'");
       simpledateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
       return simpledateformat.parse(dateHeader);
   }
```

The exception being logged in my crash-reporting system is:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 08 Jan 2015 21:16:44 GMT" (at offset 0)
   at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
   at com.mycompany.api.util.DateUtils.parseDateInHeader(DateUtils.java:45)
   at com.mycompany.api.network.procedure.NetworkProcedure.getResponseHeaders(NetworkProcedure.java:54)
   at com.mycompany.api.network.procedure.GetNetworkProcedure.run(GetNetworkProcedure.java:58)
   at com.mycompany.api.network.procedure.GetNetworkProcedure.run(GetNetworkProcedure.java:43)
   at com.mycompany.api.network.procedure.Procedure.checkedRun(Procedure.java:26)
   at com.mycompany.api.impl.BaseMendeleySdk.getDocumentTypes(BaseMendeleySdk.java:235)
   at com.mycompany.sync.SyncRequest.syncDocumentTypes(SyncRequest.java:80)
   at com.mycompany.sync.SyncRequest.sync(SyncRequest.java:57)
   at com.mycompany.sync.SyncControllerImpl$1.doInBackground(SyncControllerImpl.java:82)
   at com.mycompany.sync.SyncControllerImpl$1.doInBackground(SyncControllerImpl.java:77)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

- As you can see, the String I'm parsing is perfectly valid and follows the pattern established to the SimpleDateFormat: "Thu, 08 Jan 2015 21:16:44 GMT"
- This happens only for two clients out of hundreds in production. One being a Samsung Galaxy Note 8, and the other a Samsung Galaxy 3.
- The date comes from a response header of a HTTP request. The HTTP server is the same used by the rest of the clients, and it only fails with these two devices.

So, it's a big mistery. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss 'GMT'"` be `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss GMT"`?

Comment: Solved. This question was indeed a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062608/simpledateformat-unparseable-date?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass appropriate Locale in this case

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SimpleDateFormat uses the Locale of the phone to parse, and I was not specifying the Locate in the constructor of SimpleDateFormat, thus, it was taking the Locale of the device, which has incompatible with the format of the date.

The way to solve it is passing US as the Locale in the constructor of SimpleDateFormat, as the HTTP server prints the day of the week in English:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss 'GMT'", Locale.US);
```

The device has a Spanish locale, and in Spanish "Thu" does not exist for a week day.

Solved thanks to Michael Konietza's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062608/simpledateformat-unparseable-date?rq=1)